# Installing Tor on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnupg, tor

Hey guys I've tried installing Tor on my Ubuntu 14.04 but with no luck. I did just as the instructions in the official Tor website said but a problem appears in the middle. The instruction says:

"Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following commands at your command prompt:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -"
```

and when I type that in the Terminal this is what I get:

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/freakout/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please give output of `ls -l /home/freakout/.gnupg/gpg.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

If you have wrong permissions for ~/.gnupg contents, you need to run first.

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/*
```

Comment: This.  The other alternative is the Tor repository, but this is the easier option

Comment: It appears that I had wrong permissions. After I fixed that it all worked just fine. Thanks @Pilot6 !

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest trying this installation method (just a diff ppa from webupd8team)... straight from the source for Ubuntu 14.04+ -- https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:micahflee/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a slightly different command:

```
sudo gpg2 --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
sudo gpg2 --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

This worked for me.